# Get entire relationship from SObjectField

Tags: apex, soql, relationships, describefieldresult, sobjectfield

I am working on Selector Layer and I would like to avoid situations where the relationship name is passed as a String.

### My Goal

```java
SELECT Account.Owner.Name FROM Opportunity
```

### Approach 1: Use getRelationshipName() method

The code below works as expected, but is quite complicated, and looks ugly.

```java
System.debug(Opportunity.AccountId.getDescribe().getRelationshipName() + '.' + Account.OwnerId.getDescribe().getRelationshipName() + '.' + User.Name);
```

### Approach 2: Get relationship name from [DescribeFieldResult Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm#apex_methods_system_fields_describe)

I would like to get entire relationship from [DescribeFieldResult Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm#apex_methods_system_fields_describe).

```java
SObjectField myField = Opportunity.Account.Owner.Name;

System.debug(myField.getDescribe().getSObjectField()); // Name
System.debug(myField.getDescribe().getRelationshipName());
System.debug(myField.getDescribe().getLocalName()); // Name
System.debug(myField.getDescribe().getReferenceTargetField());
System.debug(myField.getDescribe().getName()); // Name
```

I tried all methods but failed.

### Question

Is there any simple way to get a child-to-parent relationship name?

Comment: Note that a child could have multiple relationships to the same parent

Answer (score 1):

Working from the `SObjectType`, the [getChildRelationships](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm#apex_Schema_DescribeSObjectResult_getChildRelationships) method of `DescribeSObjectResult` provides an array of [ChildRelationship](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_Schema_ChildRelationship.htm#apex_class_Schema_ChildRelationship) records that provide the information you are likely looking for e.g. `getRelationshipName`. Which field is involved is returned by `getField`.

Obviously this is from the parent side, but you can write code to talk up or down the relationships.